# Evaluate the following sum

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

I need explanation how they get to the following equation from left to right considering the partions are $\frac{n}{n}$

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{x_i}\right)\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)=\left(\frac{n}{n+2}+\frac{n}{n+4}+\frac{n}{n+6}+\cdots+\frac{n}{3n}\right)\frac{2}{n}$$

Comment: What is $x_i$ supposed to be?

Comment: the function is $\frac{1}{x}$ and if we replace that in the approximating sum formula basically it becomes $\frac{1}{x_i}$ instead of $f(x_i)$. Now I wanted to now how we reach to the above result from left to right.

Answer (score 1):

You need more information if you want to solve this properly, but trying to "reverse engineer" the thing, it looks like
$$\frac{1}{x_i}=\frac{n}{n+2i}\ ,$$
that is,
$$x_i=1+i\Bigl(\frac{2}{n}\Bigr)\ .$$
Does this fit in with the problem you are trying to solve?